# What technology can mainframe folks learn and work in the future

Tags: generics, mainframe

Can anyone please let me know what technology we can shift after reaching 10 years of experience(I.T) in mainframes. Can we learn the skills Python, Cloud(AWS/AZURE/Openstack), Data science or _ with mainframes?

Any suggestions on this.

Comment: You can learn pretty much anything you want to learn.  What would make you assume otherwise?

Comment: I want to understand the current trend for the mainframe project. Most of the mainframe projects are migrating. So just a curious to know if the below combo will helpfull to survive in the IT industry. Mainframe + Cloud or Mainframe +Python or Mainframe + Datascientist ....

Comment: There's lots of mainframe folk - mainframe system administrators, mainframe developers, mainframe data scientists (I guess),... Each of those has another "natural" development path into the distributed world and so will need to develop different additional skills.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of areas one could invest in themselves for mainframe transformation.

**Zowe.org** 
This is an open source project bringing APIs, a web UI, application mediation layer, and command line. Several tools to improve the user experience for develop, config, manage, use of mainframes are based on Zowe.

**Languages** 
Python and node.js are available on System Z.

**API enablement of appliations** 
Taking legendary mature, performant, reliable transactions and REST enabling them. Enabling cloud and mobile applications to exploit existing services. The developers consuming these APIs may not even know they are backed by the mainframe.

**DevOps** 
Adoption of DevOps for mainframe applications is also underway. Use of vscode, git, jenkins, IBM Urban Code Deploy to implement CI/CD pipelines for System Z applications.

Whatever element of mainframe you are working in, there's likely transformation there.